# Is there any application for vimium-like interaction with desktop using keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, navigation

Vimium plugin for chrome allows to follow any link on the web-page with the following actions:

1. Type `f`. It causes unique string to appear near every available link. [image: follow link with vimium]
2. Type string associated with the link you wish to follow.

Such interaction is much quicker for me than using mouse.

Is there any application for interaction with desktop in similar way? The only necessary feature is simulating left or right mouse click within any visible and clickable element.

Comment: Uhm.. no one?? I'm waiting for this kind of tool too... Too bad there is no such thing till now for Ubuntu.

Answer (score -2):

autohotkey a good hint for binding wishes wish hotkeys, a tutorial for windows ms like work-style

(https://luna-net.org/elements/ahk_sc/instr/docs/Tutorial.htm)

and the manpages for the nearly same named autokey for debian like work-style

- keyboard automation and utility for GNOME and GTK with input:
- commandline execution utility for AutoKey

  `man autokey-gtk`


  `man autokey-gtk`


  `man autokey-gtk`

konqueror address-row with

`man://autokey-run`

and

`man://autokey-gtk`


`man://autokey`

the actual thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335627/is-it-possible-to-map-vim-key-bindings-for-windows-just-like-vimium-for-chrome
and:
find it out:
https://metager.org/meta/meta.ger3?eingabe=vimium+autohotkey

Comment: Please see [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/280335)